# EF Code-First in an ecosystem of apps concerns

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a concern that I would like some input on to see if there is a solution.  We have an ecosystem of about 30 web applications that all connect to the same database.  We are going to be updating the applications and with that we are going to be moving to a new database schema.  I have a process that will be pulling all the old data into the new schema using EF Code-First for the new schema.

Well, today I ran into an issue when two branches of the solution that I wrote to migrate the data have a slightly different schema (one branch put a MaxLength on a field and an index on another).  The issue that I had was that the database was out of sync in one branch, but up-to-date in the other and the branch that was out of sync would not run until I ran Update-Database.

I was thinking about putting the code-first poco classes into a library along with the DataContext to be able to be used by the various web apps.  I would then make this library available to the team using an internal NuGet server.

My concern is that if the schema changes (doesn't happen very often, but it does happen) what happens to all of the web applications that are relying on this library for data connectivity?  Would they all break (my assumption is that they would)?  If so, all of the production web apps would be down.  Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Very good question - CFM is great for self-contained systems where the database is driven by an app's EF model, but it doesn't play nicely with others in the enterprise. IMO, I would turn off CFM and revert to a more old-school, manual, patch-controlled schema versioning mechanism which gives the backward compatability aspects a lot more thought (and revoke DBO access to your various app credentials just to be sure).

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but it may be what has to happen.